# Exploratory Factor Analysis for Smoking cessation RCT?

Tags: factor-analysis, clinical-trials, exploratory-data-analysis

So I'm planning a RCT where I'm evaluating a smoking cessation application intervention vs usual care among adolescent smokers.

For my statistical analysis I'm looking at the point prevalence of smoking abstinence (Self-reported) and I'm going to do a simple logistic regression.

Now I just had the idea that it might be interesting to do some exploratory factor analysis on the data I have. Basically at baseline I will collect information on attitudes towards smoking, self-efficacy, physical dependency to nicotine, socio-demographic information, and smoking habits from all my participants. Then at follow-up I will do the same measurements but add one questionnaire on the usage of the application for the intervention group only.

Now my question is this, would it be informative or advisable to do EFA on the intervention group to see if I can find any interesting factor loading between all the questionnaires I have and the usage of the application?

I'm not super knowledgable with EFA so correct me if I'm far off. Another idea I had was to look at the correlation between usage of the application and smoking abstinence, but if I'm doing logistic regression then that might be pointless anyway.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what aspects of the usage of the application are you tracking in your study for the intervention group?